# Ставится ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Выплату дивидендов произвести частями по приказу единственного участника из кассы организации наличными деньгами(,) либо на банковскую карту учредителя.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

По соображениям синтаксиса тут запятой не требуется. 
Однако в практике написания официальных (юридически значимых) документов подобного типа запятая перед "либо" часто проставляется вопреки общим правилам. Делается это якобы для придания присоединяемой части большей обособленности, другими словами, как *интонационный* знак.

Как тут поступить, даже не знаю. У юристов своё понимание филологии; если договор подлежит визированию у юриста, а он окажется ведомственным грамотеем, то придется эту запятую сохранить, хотя в данном случае она совершенно лишняя даже в качестве интонационной.